# return last non-zero element index in r

Tags: r

If

`a <- c(6,4,5,6,2,6,0,0,1,3,7,0,0)` #  index is 11

I need the column index of `7`.

**Purpose:**

I need to reassign value to the last non-zero element, which is the `7` in the above case.

It's guaranteed that the vector `a` always ends with `N` consecutive zeros, where `N` unknown.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try

```
 tail(which(a!=0),1)
 #[1] 11
```

Comment: You have some extra parentheses.  It should be `max(which(a!=0))`

Answer (score 1):

A more robust version that also handles the case where there are no nonzero elements:

```
max_nonzero_index <- function(a) {
   idx <- a != 0
   ifelse(any(idx), max(which(idx)), 0)
}
```

The convention here is to return 0 for the index when there are no nonzero elements.